# Find and pass multiple attributes to ajax

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

i have jquery code that finds "src" attribute of all images in div (every image has same class: .image_class), then sends it to ajax (and then to php file that finds that images and delete them).
Here is code:

```
$remove_images = $.each($("#main_div").find(".image_class").attr(""));
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'delete_images',
        imagefile: $remove_images
    },
    url: 'delete.php',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("" + msg + "");
    }
})
```

PHP file looks like this:

```
  if($_POST["action"]=="delete_images"){
    @unlink($_POST['imagefile']);
  }
```

But this does not work. I suspect something is wrong in $remove_images (lets say "$.each is bad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to collect stuff from a jQuery collection.

The callback will run for every element in the collection that is returned by `.find()` in our case. `this` will represent the current DOM element. Whatever you return from the callback will be included in the result.

```
var $remove_images = $("#main_div").find(".image_class").map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/6Um7a/)

I used the `.get()` method to convert the result into a plain Javascript array.

Please read the manual of `.map()` for further information (and in general, get used to using the manual, because you could have found the answer to your question there - the examples are great in most cases).

Comment: Also, maybe you should add a `.join('|')` to the `.get()` call above [`}).get().join('|');`]  to send the array as a string delimited with | which you can then process on the server easily. Not sure how the array will be serialized otherwise.

Comment: @techfoobar It is unnecessary. You can find information about how the [query string serialization works with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). The query string shall be in the format of `imagefile[]=1.jpg&imagefile[]=2.jpg&...`, which PHP understands.